# Create association before record is saved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So, I'm admittedly a Rails newbie, and I'm running into what must be a fairly common issue, but I can't find the answer here.

I have a model `Foo` like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end
```

Bars belongs_to Foo, all that works.  Now I want to create a Foo and build Bar at the same time.  Like this:

```
f = Foo.new(:baz => 'baz')
bars.each do |b|
  f.bars.build(:bizzy => b[:bizzy])
end
f.save
```

I know this won't work because the parent record doesn't exist, so the association doesn't exist, but there must be a way to do this.  I've temporarily gotten around it by editing to this:

```
f = Foo.new(:baz => 'baz')
f.save
f = Foo.find(:first, :conditions => {:baz => 'baz'})
bars.each do |b|
  f.bars.create(:bizzy => b[:bizzy])
end
```

But that is not clean, and is all around unpleasant.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first line you can just use `create` instead of `new`. You don't need `f.bars.create` or `f.bars.build`, because the `bar` object already exists. I would do this:

```
f = Foo.create(:baz => 'baz')

bars.each do |b|
  f.bars << b
end
```

Personally I wouldn't iterate over the `bars`, but just use `update_all`:

```
f = Foo.create(:baz => 'baz')
bars.update_all(:foo_id => f.id)
```

Edit: it's possible to do this without saving the record first. This works for me:

```
f = Foo.new(:baz => 'baz')

bars.each do |b|
  f.bars << b
end

f.save
```

Comment: Huh, I could've sworn that wasn't possible.  You are right though, after I tested it again, it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: Ran into the same issue and realised that for the last option (f = Foo.new), I had to remove `:foo_id, remove :presence => true` on the Bar model (in my own code).